# How to achieve inline-reply with iOS platform in ionic?

Tags: ios, push-notification, ionic3, phonegap-pushplugin

I am facing issue with push notification.

Actually i want to make inline-reply with ionic version 3. we are using phonegap-plugin-push (https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/PAYLOAD.md). in Android it will work perfectly fine. but in iOS it has not giving the example with inline-reply.

I have also see same functionality with native iOS and there it is working fine. we need to set some behaviour property in that. but i can not set those property while defining the categories.

Can you please check how to achieve this things in iOS ?

Let'me know if you need any further information ?

I have tried with phonegap-plugin-push.

I have already asked this question in ionic forum and created issue in phonegap-plugin-push gitHub repository. below are the link for your reference.
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/can-we-do-quick-reply-or-inline-reply-in-ios-using-push-notification/125347/5
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/issues/2823

i think we need to set property in below configuration in ionic

```
const options: PushOptions = {
      android: {
        icon: 'icon_small',
        clearNotifications: 'false',
        forceShow: 'false',
      },
      ios: {
        alert: 'true',
        badge: true,
        sound: 'false',
        categories: {
          reminder: {
            yes: {
              callback: 'confirmReminderCallback',
              title: 'CONFIRM',
              foreground: false,
              destructive: false,
              //some where over here need to set the behaviour property
            },
            no: {
              callback: 'declineReminderCallback',
              title: 'DECLINE',
              foreground: false,
              destructive: false
            }
          }
        },
        
      },
      windows: {},
      browser: {
        pushServiceURL: 'http://push.api.phonegap.com/v1/push',
      },
    };
```